# How can i apply SVM or deep neural network for image retrieval

Tags: computer-vision, svm, unsupervised-learning, cbir

After obtaining the image dataset, the feature database is constructed for all images which is a vector based on mean and sd of RGB color model and HSV color model for a portion of the image. How can I use a svm to retieve related images from the database once the query image is given.

Also how to use unsupervised learning for the above problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the query images are unlabeled, applying SVM would require a way of knowing the labels for dataset images since SVM is a form of supervised learning, which seeks to correctly determine class labels for unlabeled data. You would need another method for generating class labels, such as unsupervised learning, so this approach does not seem relevant if you only have feature vectors but no class labels.

A neural network allows for unsupervised learning with unlabeled data, but is a rather complex approach and is the subject of academic research. You may want to consider a simpler machine learning approach such as [k-Nearest Neighbors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm), which allows you to obtain the k closest training samples that are similar in your feature space. This algorithm is simple to implement and is found in many machine learning libraries. For example in Python you can use [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

I am unsure what type of images you are working with, but you might also want to explore using feature detector algorithms such as SIFT rather than just pixel intensities.

Comment: Well i am working with a database consisting of 1000 images where 100 images belong to a particular genre like holidays,beach etc. In that case what unsupervised algorithm can i use, can u please explain the entire process what needs to be followed to build such a system. Thanks in advance Micheal :-)